# Table view cell not able to get in numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, tableview

I have some index values will get change everytime. So in my vc :

```
lazy var List: [[String: Any]]? = FetchInfoUtil.sharedInstance.List

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
       print(indexPath.row)

        switch CurrentIndexVal {
        case 1:
            cell.Info = List?[0];
        case 2:
            cell.Info = List?[1];
        case 3:
            cell.Info = List?[2];
        case 4:
            cell.Info = List?[3];
        case 5:
            cell.Info = List?[4];
        case 6:
            cell.Info = List?[5];
        default:
            break;
        }

         if let gList = cell.Info?["list"]  as? [[String: Any]] {
            SelectedSkill = gList
            let gInfo = gList[indexPath.item]
            cell.Name.text = gInfo["title"] as? String ?? "NA"
        }

        return cell
    }
```

and here is an issues :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,     section: Int) -> Int {
       let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)
       let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MainTableViewCell
        guard let gList = cell?.Info?["list"]  as? [[String: Any]] else {
            return 0
       }
       return gList.count;
}
```

Here i am getting crash everytime :`let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MainTableViewCell`

Should i need to pass my `currentIndexVal` to the row or whats i am doing here.Any help will be useful for me to understand here .

Comment: Can't you just return `List!.count` ?

Comment: No, bec my List is in my table view cell. I am appending that in cell-for row at index path method

Comment: So from where you are getting that list ? You can't do it in the above mentioned way, because the numberOfRows method is called before cellForRowAt method (I mean before cell creation)

Comment: check my update post

Comment: Still my first comment is valid, did you tried that ? What's the output of that ?

Comment: your cellForRow method has its index. user indexPath.row to get the row number of the cell displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong approach in your `numberOfRows` method.
Your cell load after this method `numberOfRows`. Current cell does not have list. So in this method first get the listObject and then return its count.
Try to use below approach..

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let gList = List?[CurrentIndexVal]["list"]  as? [[String: Any]] else {
            return 0
       }
       return gList.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
       print(indexPath.row)
        let dictionaryObject = List?[CurrentIndexVal]
         if let gList = dictionaryObject?["list"]  as? [[String: Any]] {
            SelectedSkill = gList
            let gInfo = gList[indexPath.item]
            cell.Name.text = gInfo["title"] as? String ?? "NA"
        }

        return cell
    }
```

And when ever you click on the menu button and update the `CurrentIndexVal` right after updating the value in `CurrentIndexVal` just call.

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

And see the magic.

Comment: In my vc i declared initaially `lazy var List: [[String: Any]]? = FetchInfoUtil.sharedInstance.List`

Comment: But how can i use my table view cell label on outside of the delegate methods ?

Comment: Why do you want to use cell label outside the delegate method?

Comment: but ist getting crash on some places

Comment: i needs to pass the index value..or bec i have  a pagemenu controller at top. On click any menu name, i have to show one table view at bottom under each menu items. Now i am passing the index value click on menu items..based on that ia m showing data

Comment: I have update the answer. Your methods name was incorrect.

Comment: Can you display what exactly UI you want to draw?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uacaps/ResourceRepo/master/PageMenu/PageMenuDemo.gif

Comment: based on the menu click i am passing the index value in notification center and passing the values to the table view controller. And from there through the index value i am passing the index .row value and i am getting

Comment: Do you have multiple Arrays? Like one array for upper menu and one array for lower TableView?

Comment: those menu ara hardcode ..below table view data is list with having more data

Comment: Got your point. I have made changes in my methods and updated the answer as per your need. Please have a look.

Comment: then in cell for row at index path method..should i needs to use like ur answer or like my question post ?

Comment: Both are same. All you have to be careful about is return the accurate count in the numberOfRows.

Comment: In number of rows first you have to get the list of selectedIndex and then return the related count.

Comment: List is array which hold dictionaries for your above menus.
If your selected Menu index is 1. Just save this index and then in `cellForRow` method first get dictionary of this selected menu index from the List not from the cell because cell is not loaded yet. After getting the dictionary of your selected index just fetch `list` object from inside and return the count. All else of your previous code looks good.

Comment: i tried now for particular 2 index i am getting crash

Comment: Which solution have you tried? Entirely mine? or Entirely your? or Half Mine/Half Yours.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189048/discussion-between-syed-qamar-abbas-and-david).

Comment: any help on here..he is also having some issues...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865142/passworless-email-auth